# Firebase database user uid

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

this is the error Cannot convert value of type 'String     expected argument type 'User'
      var user: User?
      fileprivate func fetchUser() {

```
    let uid = user ?? (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "")

   // guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    Database.fetchUserWithUID(uid: uid) { (user) in
        self.user = user
        self.navigationItem.title = self.user?.username

        self.collectionView?.reloadData()

        self.paginatePosts()
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Explain it with an example.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: This line *let uid = user ?? (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "")* won't work. uid will either be a user *object* if it's not nil or if it is nil, then it's a string? Then *Database.fetchUserWithUID(uid: uid)* isn't going to work if it's a valid user *object* because *Database.fetchUserWithUID* expects a string parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
        if let error = error {
            // ...
            return
        }
        let uuid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    }
```

Try this one. It might solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

When you logged in Firebase Console, the UID will should on here. You also can get the User UID by android programming like below:-

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String uid = user.getUid();
```

[image]

Comment: it won't let me use FirebaseUser

Comment: May I have the error/log you have?

Comment: look at the code